# Concise way to set a default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. Is there a more elegant or concise way to do this?

```
foo = params[:foo].nil? ? 'default' : params[:foo]
```

I simply want to assign a default value if a param is not present. My way seems a bit clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a default value for one key, `Hash#fetch` is your answer.

If passed a block, it will return the value of the block if the key isn't in the params.

```
params = {}
params.fetch(:foo) { 'default' } 
=> "default"
```

If the default is easy to compute, you can just as well do this as a second argument in the method:

```
params = {}
params.fetch(:foo, 'default')
=> "default"
```

If you want to set a default for the whole hash, you should look into `#default=` and `#default_proc`.  Since your question concerns `params`, I'm guessing you can't initialize the hash with an appropriate default.

BTW, your way will not return `nil` if the value is set to `nil`, but fetch will properly return `nil`.

```
params[:foo] = nil
params.fetch(:foo) { 'default' }
=> nil
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I like:

```
 foo = params[:foo] || 'default'
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Everybody should know the OR operator can be used to set default values.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter equivalent of:

```
foo = params[:foo].nil? ? 'default' : params[:foo]
```

is

```
foo = params[:foo] || 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `presence` method, check this code:

```
foo = params[:foo].presence || 'default'
```

- `presence` checks if the value is present (i.e. is not `nil`/empty), if it is, it returns that value, if not, it returns `nil`.
- `||` will return the value to its *right* if the one its *letf* is `nil`.

Please note that this option will also set `foo` to `'default'` if `params[:foo]` is empty.